# Eigenvalue of some Sturm–Liouville problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have one simple question.
How I suppose to show that $\lambda =0$ is an eigenvalue of some problem.
Does it mean that I must have non-trivial solution for $\lambda=0 $?

Thanks!

UPD:I mean by problem some Sturm–Liouville equation...

Comment: If your (hopefully) matrix is low dimensional, you may try proving determinant is zero.

Comment: @ Tapu I mean by problem some Sturm–Liouville equation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that $A$ is a linear operator of some vector space. Then $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue if and only if there exists non-zero vector $x$ such that $Ax= \lambda x$. In the case of $\lambda=0$, we must have $Ax=0, x \neq 0$.

Answer (score 4):

Find a vector $v$ such that :

1) $v$ is not zero ;

2) $Av = 0$, where $A$ is the matrix in your problem.

Comment: $A$ does not have to be a matrix, could be any linear operator -- as in Manos's answer

Comment: Sure, but I am keeping it simple for Panka.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you must have a non-trivial solution for $\lambda=0$. For example, the SL problem $y^{\prime\prime}+\lambda y=0$, with boundary conditions $y^{\prime}(0)=0$, $y^{\prime}(1)=0$ has $\lambda=0$ for an eigenvalue with $y(x)=c$, where $c \neq 0$ is a constant for an eigenfunction.